# Custom Customer Attribute filter on search criteria Magento 2.1.8

Tags: attributes, customer, collection, magento-2.1.7

I am trying to get `customer collection` based on `email_id` and my custom customer attributes i.e `phone_code` and `mobile_number`.

When I only add `email` filter getList return's `customer array` object but when I add my custom filter of `mobile_number` and `phone_code` attribute it return's 0 element error.

So is there any way we can use custom customer attributes in Search Criteria.

**My Sample code:**

```
$customerRepository = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface;

$email[] = $this->_filterBuilder
->setField('email')
->setValue($row[5])
->setConditionType('eq')
->create();
$phonecode[] = $this->_filterBuilder
->setField('phone_code')
->setValue($row[7])
->setConditionType('eq')
->create();
$mobile[] = $this->_filterBuilder
->setField('mobile_number')
->setValue($row[11])
->setConditionType('eq')
->create();

$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
->addFilters($email)
->addFilters($phonecode)
->addFilters($mobile) 
->create(); 

$customerCollection = $customerRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

Comment: what's in `$row` array ?

Comment: it is just some value you can assume $row[5]="abc@gmail.com", $row[7]="65" and $row[11]="00000110"

Comment: Hi All,

It's working fine now, it was because of my data was not correctly saved for particular customer. Thanks.